# create image from url using imagecreatefromjpeg

Tags: php, image

I want to create image from php using the function `imagecreatefromjpeg(string $filename )`,
but when I am providing a image URL as a parameter to this function then this function is not able to create image.

```
$pic = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://www.example.com/image.jpg');

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

imagejpeg($pic);

imagedestroy($pic);
```

Comment: When something doesn't work, then the first thing to do is turning up `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 2):

You can actually create images from remote files, but please be sure the 'fopen wrappers' have been enabled, see also http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

if it doesn't work, what kind of error do you see? and what kind of variable is `$pic`?

Answer (score 1):

I can't check this right now, but i'd wager it has to be a local file. I.e. you need to have the file on your server.

php.net says: A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php)